# How to automate Caps Lock Delay Removal in macOS MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, applescript, automator

I'll start with quoting another Stack Overflow user:

> Apple's MacBook Pro has a slight delay on the caps lock key. That is, the caps lock key has to be held down slightly longer than normal to register the key press required to engage the caps lock.*

It appears that by remapping the caps-lock key on macOS (in System Preferences, Keyboard, Modifier Keys), the delay goes away until reboot.

I would like to **automate this settings configuration remapping with a script and to set it to run at startup**. I have tried to use Automator but with no luck.
How can we achieve this?

*Quote reference:
[How to remove caps lock delay on Apple MacBook Pro aluminum keyboard when booted to Linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81234/how-to-remove-caps-lock-delay-on-apple-macbook-pro-aluminum-keyboard-when-booted/)

Answer (score 2):

I've developed a very lightweight, open source app for mac to solve this exact problem.

https://github.com/gkpln3/CapsLockNoDelay

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a script but I just fixed this a few minutes ago on my Macbook Pro. Here are the steps I took:

Go to **System Preferences > Accessibility >** scroll down to **keyboard >** look for checkbox **Enable Slow Keys** (If it is not ticked go ahead and tick it) **>** Go to **Options...** directly across from it.

Then move the **Acceptance Delay** all the way to **Short**.

Hit OK and you're done. No more CAPS LOCK delay.

*Edit: Another post mentioned that this will make your Backspace take a little longer than usual to delete individual characters when holding the button down.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This solution does actually solves the problem in a different way, although it introduces another problem as you state in your post. I am trying this right now.
I am still looking forward to find a way to automate a script for the other settings option, which I believe would address the problem at its best, but in the meantime I thank you for your effort in solving the problem :)

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem because adjusting slow keys to 0 makes repeatable actions such as deleting text (holding backspace) very slow and unusable.

Comment: This solves the problem for me but unfortunately also breaks mute and play/pause on the touch bar: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316811/366881